# Sitecore 8.0 Update-3 WebEdit Palette.aspx error

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

I've been searching for the fix of this issue for some time today, but I still got no luck to find the root cause. Maybe someone else encountered the same scenario and able to fix the issue. Thanks in advance.

Okay, basically I already migrated one of my client production SC instance to my local machine for an upgrade simulation from 8.0-U3 to 8.1-U2, and it is up and running in terms of accessing the CM (content editor, experience editor, publish and other more) and the health of logging is quite good.

**Note that:** I haven't started the simulation, so this is still in v.8.0-U3

Until I opened a page using Experience Editor (still good) and start adding new component (clicked the *add here* button), and then, I encountered the Palette.aspx *500 internal server error* after checking it in the browser console log.

```
POST http://8.0-u3.sitecore.com/sitecore/shell/Applications/WebEdit/Palette.aspx 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

And so, as most curious developer will do, I opened the URL to see the full stack trace:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Palette.aspx: unrecognized command ''

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Exception: Palette.aspx: unrecognized command ''

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[Exception: Palette.aspx: unrecognized command '']
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Palette.OnPreInit(EventArgs e) +2380
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +46
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1251
```

I also checked the SC log file, to see what it tells me:

```
16220 2016:04:29 17:37:12 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.sitecore_shell_applications_webedit_palette_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\bf95a62a\ceceb3fc\App_Web_mqggjnpz.2.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.FormatException
Message: Unrecognized Guid format.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result)
   at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
   at Sitecore.Data.ShortID..ctor(String id)
   at Sitecore.Data.ShortID.Parse(String value)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.ExecuteInsertRenderingArgs.<GetAllowedRenderingsIds>b__0(String id)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.InsertRendering.InsertRenderingAt(DeviceDefinition device, RenderingDefinition renderingDefinition, Int32 insertPosition, IEnumerable`1 allowedRenderingsIds)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.InsertRendering.Process(PipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.ExecutePageEditorActionPipeline.Run(ExecutePageEditorActionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Palette.OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

So I made some investigation and tweaking, I commented out the WebEdit Palette from Sitecore.AntiCSRF.config, just to check if there's any difference (seems not the right solution)

**My self-arguement:** Why do I have to edit this at all?

```
<ignore contains="WebEdit/Palette"/>
```

The previous SC log was not existing anymore, but got a new one below.

```
18404 2016:04:29 18:46:28 ERROR Application error.
Exception: Sitecore.Security.AntiCsrf.Exceptions.PotentialCsrfException
Message: CSRF form field is missing.
Source: Sitecore.Security.AntiCsrf
   at Sitecore.Security.AntiCsrf.SitecoreAntiCsrfModule.RaiseError(Exception ex, HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.Security.AntiCsrf.SitecoreAntiCsrfModule.PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Unfortunately, up to this point, the error still persist and I still wasn't able to add new component because it returns a **An error occurred** pop up.

Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

I've recently experienced the same issue on my environment. In my case it was because adding the component in certain placeholders was breaking the html structure and causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's having a problem parsing a Guid from the Allowed Renderings on your placeholder settings.  Make sure you have only valid renderings selected.  You may want to view the raw value to make sure it is a properly formatted pipe-delimited list of Guids.

Answer (score 1):

It happened when we added a class in default.cshtml on the layout page. the JS frameworks conflicted